# Adding more than one text box to HTML from Visual Basic code behind?

Tags: html, vb.net

I'm trying to add a text box whenever a user presses a certain button. 
The text box is being successfully added the first time the user presses on that button. However, nothing is getting added when pressing the button again.

My code is:

Html:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAdd" Text="Add" CssClass="button"/>
<div id="divAdd" runat="server" > </div>
```

Code Behind:

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
   Dim textbox As New TextBox
   textbox.Text = "test"
   divAdd.Controls.Add(textbox)
End Sub
```

Is there a way to add the text box to the same div every time the btnAdd button is pressed?
Note: Without using a for loop

Comment: It probably is. Look at setting the location of the `TextBox`. As it stands they are probably overlapping.

Comment: I don't think that this is the problem. I tried putting a line break after creating the text box.. And i also checked the View Page source page. There was only one text box added

Answer (score 0):

Because of complete post back previous created button goes and you only see the newly created